# Cannot call function from dynamically loaded javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm loading a javascript external file from another javascript file present in the document and since its loaded, I want to call a function from the loaded js file. 
Here is the load function:

```
function loadScript(url) {
    var head = window.top.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = window.top.document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.type= "text/javascript";
    head.appendChild(script);
    if(script.readyState) {  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ( script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete" ) {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                console.log("[BANDEAU] script loaded");
                testAlert();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function() {
            console.log("[BANDEAU] script loaded");
            testAlert();
        };
    }
}
```

So it works nice because the javascript file is succesfuly loaded but I cannot access the `testAlert()` method from the loaded javascript file, as I try in the code above, right after printing that the script is loaded. When I try to get the type of the function with `typeOf` on `window[testAlert]`, I get an undefined. But when I try to execute the `testAlert()` method in the developer console, it works perfectly. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong ?

Does the position in the DOM between the caller javascript file and the loaded javascript file might be the reason ?

Comment: Why are you appending the script to `window.top` instead of `window`?

Comment: To put it another way: when that code runs, is `window` the same as `window.top` or not? If they're different, then that's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the load handlers BEFORE changing the src

```js
function loadScript(url) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; // window.top in frames/iFrames
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript";

  if (script.readyState) { //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        console.log("[BANDEAU] script loaded");
        testAlert(); // window.top.testAlert() if needed
      }
    };
  }
  else {
    script.onload = function() {
      console.log("[BANDEAU] script loaded");
      testAlert(); // window.top.testAlert() if needed
    };
  }
  script.src = url;
  head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: @HubertSolecki are you loading that file from an `<iframe>` or something?

Comment: @Pointy yes... just noticed that.... Just needed to add parent keyword right before my testAlert function...

Comment: @HubertSolecki right, `window.parent.testAlert()` or `window.top.testAlert()`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what mplungjan said, I'm pretty sure you'd have to do an eval() on the loaded script in order to have a legitimate address for the call to testAlert().

Also, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) for more info.

Comment: Keep in mind that eval() is dangerous, so I wouldn't recommend it as a long-term solution. The link I provided features more mature (and safer) solutions.

Comment: This is untrue. The OP is creating a `<script>` tag and appending it to the document; the normal behavior of a `<script>` tag is that the browser loads the code and runs it.

Comment: True. The parent does run the code, but the `loadScript()` function won't automatically receive a pointer to `testAlert()`. But I see your answer in the above comment, and that totally works; reference `testAlert()` with `window.parent.testAlert()`. That's a lot better than my idea of using eval().

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. The problem was that I called the function within an iFrame, juts noticed that so I needed to call the function on the parent pointer.